# Textfield draggable on Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, textfield, draggable

Do you know how can i make a textfield draggable on flutter and also that its height and its width increases while the user types (not predetermined) ?

The idea is put like every user can write something and move it across the screen.
Im savings the screen coordinates in order, that if the user enters from another device will see the text in the location he left it before.

If already tried with a code i found that uses positioned and stuff but since i have to predefine the width/height of the box, the offset location is not accurate when im showing it on other screen.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try using the InteractiveViewer,
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InteractiveViewer-class.html

Comment: Simply posting a link isn't an answer. Write a comment instead.